# Postgres Queries Work on 9.0 but not on 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying this query on my postgres 9.2

```
SELECT ar.nome_defensor, count(*)
FROM sirdp.atividade_realizadas ar
INNER JOIN sirdp.naturezas n on n.id = ar.natureza_id
INNER JOIN sirdp.atividades at on at.id = n.atividade_id
WHERE ar.data_atividade between '01/08/2011' and '31/08/2014'
    and ar.local_atuacao_defensor in ('1ª Vara de Acara\303\272')
group by ar.nome_defensor
order by ar.nome_defensor
```

It don't work, but on 9.0 it works.

I think it has something with the parameter: `1ª Vara de Acara\303\272` because the problem is with accented words.

Both database have this config:

```
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
   LC_CTYPE = 'pt_BR.UTF-8'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: If this problem "only" exists from within Ruby, make sure to add the relevant Ruby code and then re-add the tag. In any case, my first step would be to create a *minimal* reproduction case - e.g. a query that *only* has the suspected parameter - to isolate exactly "which part" exhibits different behavior.

Comment: I tried the query via pgadmin, the ruby inteface uses a pure string method to send it via dbi.

Comment: What do you mean "It don't work": query returns not expected results or server reports error? In any case provide more information: what's wrong with results or what is the error message.

Comment: What's the overall context for that `'1ª Vara de Acara\303\272'`? Is that inside a single-quoted Ruby string context or double-quoted? If it is in a double-quote context then the string is really `1ª Vara de Acaraú` but the backslashed-octals won't be interpreted as bytes in a single quoted context.

Comment: Define "works". Exactly. What output do you get on 9.0 vs 9.2? If there's an error message, what's the exact text of the error? Also please show output of `\l mydatabasename` in `psql` on both 9.0 and 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it has something with the parameter: 1ª Vara de Acara\303\272
>   because the problem is with accented words.

Yes. Postgresql 9.0 and before had the configuration parameter `standard_conforming_strings` set to OFF by default, which means that this string literal:

```
'1ª Vara de Acara\303\272'
```

was interpreted in the context of UTF-8 encoding as: `1ª Vara de Acaraú`

Since PostgreSQL 9.1, this `standard_conforming_strings` has been turned to ON by default, so now the backslash is interpreted as just a backslash. This is explained in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html):

> **standard_conforming_strings (boolean)**
>       This controls whether ordinary string literals ('...') treat backslashes literally, as specified in the SQL standard. Beginning in
>   PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on (prior releases defaulted to off).
>   Applications can check this parameter to determine how string literals
>   will be processed. The presence of this parameter can also be taken as
>   an indication that the escape string syntax (E'...') is supported.
>   Escape string syntax (Section 4.1.2.2) should be used if an
>   application desires backslashes to be treated as escape characters.

You may get away with this by either:

- Using directly `1ª Vara de Acaraú` in the query. After all this, `ª` character is not in the US-ASCII range already, so your method to submit the query already supports accents.
- Using `E'1ª Vara de Acara\303\272'` in the query.
- Not changing the query, but setting `standard_conforming_strings` to OFF to switch back to the behavior of PostgreSQL 9.0 and previous versions.